# Date format string for a date string

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

In Object-C, how about the date format string for the following date string:

> 2017:04:11 17午後5:40:00

I have tried `"yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss a"` and set Locale is `currentLocale`.
My device is in Japanese language, 24hour display is OFF.

Comment: Certainly `17午後5:40:00` is not in the format of `HH:mm:ss a`. `a` is for am/pm. Google translate tells me that `午後` means "afternoon". Is `17` the hour? What are the other 3 sets of numbers?

Comment: All your questions have answer is "Yes". Thanks.

Comment: How is the original date/time string generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at all the parts of the string you want (I hope I got them correctly - otherwise just look up the correct format characters in the link below):

- `2017` year with four digits: `yyyy`
- `04` month with two digits: `MM`
- `11` day with two digits: `dd`
- `17` hour in 24h hour format with two digits: `HH`
- `午後` am/pm string: `a`
- `5` hour in 12h format with one or two digits: `h`
- `40` minute with 2 digits: `mm`
- `00` seconds with 2 digits: `ss`

Combined: `yyyy:MM:dd HH a h:mm:ss`

For a reference of the strings (OS X >= v10.9 and iOS >= 7) see [Unicode standard 35](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) (for links for older versions see [Appels Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13))

```c
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy:MM:dd HH a h:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:513650400];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
// Output: 2017:04:11 17 午後 5:40:00
```

Comment: Thanks you for your comment. It is useful. The problem is more complicated. In the same date string above when we switch the device into English (US). It turns into: 2017:04:11 5:40:00 PM. So if we use the above string format and change locale for NSDateFormatter. It is seem as not resolve the problem.

Comment: If I run my code sample with the English locale I get `2017:04:11 17 PM 5:40:00`, do I get it right that you want `2017:04:11 5:40:00 PM` instead if the user sets the device to English? If so, this is not possible with one string, you will need to check the users locale and than switch the format string based on it.

Comment: This is my problem. I think that NSFormatter and right locale, it will understand the position of "a" correctly.  Maybe it doesn't use format string. It may set NSDateFormatter some thing to get this.